# Key and value types in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, generics, types, typescript3.0

```js
interface A { a?: number };
interface B { a?: string };

function copy<
    Source extends object,
    Destination extends { [destinationKey in keyof Source]?: (1) }
>(
    source: Source,
    key: keyof Source,
    destination: Destination,
    transformer: (value: (2)) => (3) 
) {
    if (source[key] !== undefined) {
        destination[key] = transformer ? transformer(source[key]) : source[key];
    }
}

const a: A = { a: 123 };
const b: B = {};

copy(a, "a", b, (value) => value.toString());
```

In the above example, what can I use for the following placeholders:

- **(1)** - type of value in `Destination` associated with the corresponding key in `Source`.
- **(2)** - type of value in `Source` associated with the key specified by parameter `key`.
- **(3)** - type of value in `Destination` associated with the key specified by parameter `key`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an extra type parameter representing the actual key that will be passed in. This parameter will be inferred to a string literal type based on the value passed in to the `key` parameter. With this new type we can use type queries to get the specific property in type in the `Source` and `Destination` types.

Also since we only care about the specific `K` key we can use it when we defined the `Destination` type as having it (instead of specifying that `Destination` must have all keys of `Source`). Since we don't really care about the type of the destination property, just that it exists and that the `transformer` function must return a value of the same type as this property we can just specify the type of the property in  `Destination` as `unknown`.

```
interface A { a?: number };
interface B { a?: string };

function copy<
    K extends keyof Source, // The extra type parameter
    Source extends object,
    Destination extends { [destinationKey in K]?: unknown } // Can be anything we don't really care, we only care about the K key existing
>(
    source: Source,
    key: K, // The key is of type K
    destination: Destination,
    transformer: (value: Source[K]) => Destination[K] // We use K to specify the relation between Source and Destination property type
) {
    if (source[key] !== undefined) {
        destination[key] = transformer ? transformer(source[key]) : source[key];
    }
}

const a: A = { a: 123 };
const b: B = {};

copy(a, "a", b, (value) => value.toString());
copy(a, "a", b, (value) => value); /// error
```